# Pathing of bones doesn't make sense

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

So basically, with how I have the armature animated, the location of the foot does not end up completely exact with where it started. Now this wouldn't be a problem, such a small shift would most likely not be noticed. The big issue is that the bones don't follow a straight line, but instead take a big loop, making the motion much more noticeable than it has to be. Is there any way to fix the pathing, or will I have to make sure the bones of the foot end in the exact same position? I am still fairly new to Blender, so sorry if this has an answer that feels like common knowledge [image: Background bones don't matter, just the two in front with the most sharp loops]

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with "root bone". There's not much explanation out there that deals with this issue. This is the best I can find. Hopefully it helps. [Unreal + Blender Tutorial - How to add root bones / motion or keep animations in place](https://youtu.be/YuIUrKNw52M?si=J4naIFXoyrgHorMp)